# Combining conventional routing and attribute routing in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-routing

I've tried to combine conventional and attribute routing together.

However it doesn't work as expected, probably because I've missed to do something.

What I have so far:

Routing:

```
builder.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Home Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Attribute Mapped Controller:

```
[Route("Admin")]
public class AdminLockController : Controller
{
    [Route("ControlCenter")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
<img id="app-logo-image" src="/img/corporate_logo.png"/>
</a>
```

Now when when the view Home\Index.cshtml get rendered the link in _Layout.cshtml will become 
`<a href="/"></a>` (Correct).

But when the view AdminLock\Index.cshtml get rendere the link is `<a href=""></a>` (Wrong).

So I guess I need to do some extra configuration, but no idea what. Any hints?

**UPDATE 1:**
It works perfectly in a new created mvc project. So it has to be something wrong in my project... i will try to find out what the issue is...

Comment: Try `<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"></a>`

Comment: Do you perhaps have duplicate calls to `.UseMvc()` in your Startup.cs? That was the problem here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4658

Comment: @GabrielLuci nope just once.

Comment: @J.Doe same result

Comment: Does the new project have route attributes on the Home controller too?

Comment: @GabrielLuci no i made one with and one without, same as my real app. I wild guess that a service or a middleware is messing up the routing. I will start to include the one i use in my real app in the new project and hope for enlightenment :)

Comment: @GabrielLuci found the issue (see answer). Thanks for your help you brought me to the idea that the some middleware can have impact, that helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Issue.

I'm using the Smidge as a bundler and Minifier.

I registred the Smidge Middleware before the Mvc Middleware. That seems to mess up the routing. I opened an Issue on githup. See https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge/issues/71

Changing the order fixes the problem.